# how to improve speed on MySQL like wildcards '%search%', or alternate database

Tags: php, mysql, performance, mongodb

I have a database of about 5 million records. I need a prefix wild card, which is mildly slow.

Besides getting rid of the wild card and full text searches, any ideas how I could improve speed on the query?

I am willing to use different tools as well, like MongoDB if that would help. I'm not sure if any of those will actually be faster though.

Comment: Consider using [FULL TEXT SEARCH](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html) instead of LIKE, or tools like [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/)

Comment: MongoDB wouldn't be faster. Consider using a search engine like Solr if MySQL full text search doesn't fix the problem

Comment: Is the 'search' string inside the wildcards going to be the same every time, or can this be anything? If you have one (or a small number) of possibilities, you can pre-cache search solutions to make them faster when they are requested.

Comment: Do you need prefix and suffix at the same time?  If not, reverse the string the TEXT and the query; then you have a trailing wildcard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solr is the best option for full text search IMHO. You can configure it to fetch data from mysql and populate its own records. The main drawback is that any schema modification of the Solr dataset will need a complete index rebuild (fetching data again from mysql).

Comment: Thanks rod (and martin). I've settled for mysql FULL TEXT for now due to time, but I am going to investigate Solr for future use.

Answer (score 0):

Indexing might help. Try indexing at the table's entity and then to check the query time.